# Passing data back from DialogFragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a search field set up in a dialogfragment, then when users click to open initially, allows them to enter a title and hit search. I want this to be able to communicate back to the Activity's listview.

Unfortunately I keep getting a crash when attempting to search. I have it set up using a listener, but I believe it has to do with attempting to read the textView from the MainActivity's layout, even though it's in the DialogFragment'a layout xml?

I attempt to call it by R.id.searchField in the MainActivity which onCreate's setContent's layout XML is different from the one the DialogFragment implements. I get no error when trying to do so , just the fatal crash. Not sure why else I would receive an error, Here is the code, and stack trace below it:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements searchListener{
public void searchBooks() 
    {
// Error is in this function, believe it has to do with this textField as it resides in // the DialogFragment's xml? Unless findViewById calls from all XMLS and just not one defined in 
//setContentView for the activity? Not sure though, initially I feel I should have this searchField 
//defined in the fragment class, but then I won't have access to it in this function in MainActivity, 
//or the mResults which is where the data is being used

        EditText searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchField);

        if (mResults != null && !searchField.getText().equals(""))
        {

            String inputedText = searchField.getText().toString();
            JSONArray results = new JSONArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < mResults.length(); i++)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject bookObject = mResults.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (bookObject.get("name").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(inputedText))
                    {
                        results.put(bookObject);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
public void showDialog() {
    DialogFrag newFragment = DialogFrag.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Setting the main view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
}
}
```

DialogFragment:

```
public class DialogFrag extends DialogFragment {
    public static DialogFrag newInstance() {
        return new DialogFrag();
    }
    private searchListener listener;
    public interface searchListener
    {
        public void searchBooks();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (searchListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "attaching d fragment failed!");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog_fragment, container, false);

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.searchBooks();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

StackTrace

```
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260): Process: com.brentadams.bookList, PID: 11260
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at com.brentadams.bookList.MainActivity.searchBooks(MainActivity.java:327)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at com.brentadams.bookList.fragments.SearchFragment$1.onClick(SearchFragment.java:48)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-29 20:10:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11260):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT NEW CODE / ERRORS:

Took your advice and have the string passed back into method searchBooks, but now recieving a stupid nullpointerexception on what I think doesn't make any sense. The textview resides in my activity_main_fragment.xml:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements searchListener{
public void searchBooks(String searchString) 
    { 


        if (mResults != null && searchString != null && !searchString.equals(""))
        {


            JSONArray results = new JSONArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < mResults.length(); i++)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject bookObject = mResults.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (bookObject.get("name").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(searchString))
                    {
                        results.put(bookObject);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
public void showDialog() {
    DialogFrag newFragment = DialogFrag.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Setting the main view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
}
}
```

DialogFragment

```
public class DialogFrag extends DialogFragment {
    public static DialogFrag newInstance() {
        return new DialogFrag();
    }
    private searchListener listener;
    public interface searchListener
    {
        public void searchBooks(String text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (searchListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "attaching d fragment failed!");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog_fragment, container, false);

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText searchField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.searchField);
                String input = searchField.getText().toString();
                listener.searchBooks(input);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.brentadams.bookList.fragments.SearchFragment$1.onClick(SearchFragment.java:51)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-29 15:30:31.402: E/AndroidRuntime(777):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 51:

```
        String input = searchField.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Posted it thanks for taking the time to look!

Comment: what is line 327 `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: if (mResults != null && !searchField.getText().equals(""))

Comment: `searchField` is null. Do you have it in `activity_main_fragment.xml`

Comment: No I have it in my fragments XML, which is why I think I'm recieving the error- but I cannot simply move this to my activity_main_fragment.xml because then I wouldn't be able to access it in my Fragment the way the logic is set up.

Comment: you need to use interface as a callback to the activity to communicate values from fragment to activity. But what you do  is wrong and hence the error

Comment: In your `searchListener` interface, change the `searchBooks` method to accept a string, i.e., define it as `public void searchBooks(String searchString);`. Then, in your `DialogFrament` `onClick(...)` method, get the string from the `EditText` and pass it to `listener.searchBooks(myString);`

Comment: Tried that, now get another error. Your logic sounds perfect though not sure why I'm getting a NullPointerException on this line:                 String textInput = searchField.getText().toString();

Comment: Updated post, tried what you both recommended and got a new odd error that doesn't make much sense of me why it's returning nullexception when something is typed in the textview upon button click.

Comment: Actually think I fixed it, I believe it was utilizing the View v defined in onClick rather then the one defined in the onCreateView, hense the crash. I simply changed the one defined in onCreateView to final, and renamed the paramter to View view in Onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah, the problem is the R.id.searchfield.  It's not a view that is a child of your MainActivity's rootview, its a child of the the dialog fragment.

The null pointer is occurring because it doesn't find R.id.searchfield, and searchfield is null as a result, which crashes you on the next line or so, when you call searchField.getText().

Just have your dialogfrag search the text field and pass back a string to your main activity.

Comment: Updated my post, Tried what you said and got a new odd error that doesn't make much sense of me why it's returning nullexception when something is typed in the textview upon button click.

Comment: Actually think I fixed it, I believe it was utilizing the View v defined in onClick rather then the one defined in the onCreateView, hense the crash. I simply changed the one defined in onCreateView to final, and renamed the paramter to View view in Onclick.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById()` will only find views located in the layout file you specified in `setContentView()`. You need to either move the `TextView` into your `Activity's` layout or move this logic into your `Fragment`.

Comment: That's the issue I'm running into I thought. But I simply cannot move the TextView into my Activity's layout, because then it wouldn't display in my DialogFragment. I cannot move the logic into my fragment, because all of the mResult data and what not is being stored within MainActivity.